# Mongoose return doc if every sub doc in array has a certain field and value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Want to use Mongoose Model.findOneAndUpdate() to only find a doc if every sub doc in array has a certain field and value.

In example 1 below, I want to frame the find query such that it checks to see every sub doc in array has day: 'Monday' and count: 0. That query would match the doc and make it available for update.

But the same query will not work for example 2 as sub doc groupB has day: 'Tuesday', so no doc will be returned for an update.

```
Example 1 -->
{
  count: 0;
  groupOffDays: [
    {
      group: A,
      day: 'Monday'
    },
    {
      group: B,
      day: 'Monday'
    },
    {
     group: C,
     day: 'Monday'
   },
  ]
}

Example 2 -->
{
  count: 0;
  groupOffDays: [
    {
      group: A,
      day: 'Monday'
    },
    {
      group: B,
      day: 'Tuesday'  <--match fails as sub doc does not have a value of Monday
    },
    {
     group: C,
     day: 'Monday'
   },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Post your query which you have tried

Comment: Was giving it a try in mongo shell first(before trying it in mongoose) to see how I could find the object with the applied filters --> `code db.mycoll.find({groupOffDays: { $all:[ {"$elemMatch": {day:"Monday"}}  ] } })` This returns the object even if one element in array meets the condition, was looking for a way to have it not retrn the doc for Example 2.

Comment: You can do it easily if you can adjust your structure to key value pair. Something like  `groupOffDays: [
{group:'A', day: 'Monday'}
  ]` and you can use aggregation. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Arrgh typo in me initial example. My structure is actually what you outlined Veeram.  Can you tell me how I can use aggregation, I am a noob here.